# Kendo Grid with lock columns offsetting unlocked columns alignment vertical and horizontal

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid that is using locked columns and some columns are templates, the problem I am running into is that the columns that aren't locked are not properly aligned with its header as well as the rows start going out of alignment.

Has anyone come across this and if so were you able to resolve it.

Here is the grid

```
function CreateQuickEntryGrid() {
        itemRowIndex = -1;

        $("#QuickEntryGrid").empty();
        quickEntryGrid = $("#QuickEntryGrid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                data: addBlankRows([]),
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "CatalogID",
                        fields: {
                            CatalogID: { editable: false, type: "number", title: "#" },
                            Catalog: { defaultValue: "Catalog1", editable: true, hidden: true },
                            Area: { type: "string", editable: true, hidden: false },
                            Section: { editable: false, type: "string", hidden: true },
                            PN: { type: "string", editable: true },
                            Qty: { type: "number", editable: true, validation: { min: 0, required: true } },
                            ItemID: { type: "string", editable: true },
                            Name: { type: "string", editable: true },
                            Description: { type: "string", editable: false },
                            ItemIAM: { type: "string", editable: true, hidden: true },
                            ItemKey: { type: "string", editable: true, hidden: true },
                            AutoAttachmentType: { type: "number", editable: true, hidden: true },
                            Width: { editable: true, type: "string" },
                            Height: { editable: true, type: "string" },
                            Depth: { editable: true, type: "string" },
                            Hinge: { editable: true, type: "string" },
                            FinishSideLeft: { editable: true, type: "string" },
                            FinishSideRight: { editable: true, type: "string" },
                            FromImplementorToFactory: { editable: true, type: "string" },
                            ItemListPrice: { editable: true, type: "number" },
                            ItemGlobalListPrice: { editable: true, type: "number" },
                            Multiplier: { editable: true, type: "number" },
                            Markup: { editable: true, type: "number" },
                            ImplementorCostEach: { editable: true, type: "number" },
                            EachSell: { editable: true, type: "number" },
                            Total: { editable: true, type: "number" },
                            HasPrompts: { type: "boolean", editable: true, hidden: true },
                            IsAttachment: { type: "boolean", editable: true, hidden: true },
                            ItemRowNumber: { type: "number", editable: false, hidden: false }
                        }
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 50
            },
            sortable: false,
            navigatable: true,
            reorderable: false,
            groupable: false,
            filterable: false,
            columnMenu: false,
            pageable: false,
            selectable: "row",
            toolbar: [
                {
                    name: "create",
                    template:
                        "<button id='btnInsertBlankItem' type='button' class='btn btn-warning btn-xs' onclick='insertBlankItem()'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span> Insert Blank</button>&nbsp;"
                },
                {
                    name: "openItemBlade",
                    template:
                        "<button type='button' id='btnInsertItem' class='btn btn-warning btn-xs' onclick='insertItem()'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span> Add Item or Att/Acc/Mod</button>&nbsp;"
                },
                {
                    text: "Delete",
                    template:
                        "<button type='button' class='btn btn-warning btn-xs' onclick='DeleteSelectRow()'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Delete</button>&nbsp;"
                },
                {
                    text: "Global List Prices",
                    template:
                        "<button id='btnShowGlobalListPrices' type='button' class='btn btn-warning btn-xs'><span class='fa fa-dollar'></span> Price Breakdown</button>"
                }
            ],
            edit: function (e) {
                ...
            },
            dataBound: function (e) {
                ...
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "ItemRowIndex",
                    title: "ItemRowIndex",
                    template: "#= IncrementItemRowIndex() #",
                    hidden: true,
                    locked: true
                },
                {
                    field: "ItemRowNumber",
                    title: "#",
                    locked: true,
                    width: "55px",
                    template: "#= renderNumber(ItemRowNumber) #",
                    hidden: false,
                    editable: false,
                    attributes: {
                        style: "background-color: lightgray; border-color:darkgrey"
                    }
                },
                {
                    field: "Section",
                    title: "Section",
                    locked: true,
                    width: "80px",
                    hidden: true
                },
                {
                    field: "Area",
                    title: "Area",
                    locked: true,
                    width: "60px",
                    editor: AreaDropDownEditor,
                    template: "#= Area #",
                    hidden: false,
                    attributes: {
                        class: "editable-cell"
                    }
                },
                {
                    field: "PN",
                    title: "PN",
                    width: "40px",
                    template: "#= getItemPromptTemplate(PN) #",
                    locked: true
                },
                {
                    field: "Qty",
                    title: "Qty",
                    locked: true,
                    width: "50px",
                    attributes: {
                        class: "editable-cell"
                    },
                    editor: function (container, options) {
                        $('<input data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
                            .appendTo(container)
                            .kendoNumericTextBox({
                                min: 0,
                                step: 1,
                                format: "0",
                                spinners: false,
                                select: function (e) {
                                    let dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item);
                                    let grid = $("#QuickEntryGrid").data("kendoGrid");
                                    let rowItem = grid.dataItem(container.parent());
                                    rowItem.set("Qty", dataItem.Value);
                                },
                                change: function (e) {
                                    let dataItem = $("#QuickEntryGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem(container.parent());
                                }
                            });
                    }
                },
                {
                    field: "ItemID",
                    title: "ItemID",
                    width: "100px",
                    hidden: true,
                    locked: true
                },
                {
                    field: "Name",
                    title: "Name",
                    locked: true,
                    editor: NameDropDownEditor,
                    width: "100px",
                    attributes: {
                        class: "editable-cell"
                    }
                },
                {
                    field: "ItemKey",
                    title: "Item Key",
                    width: "100px",
                    hidden: true
                },
                {
                    field: "AutoAttachmentType",
                    title: "AutoAttachmentType",
                    width: "100px",
                    hidden: true
                },
                {
                    field: "IsAttachment",
                    title: "IsAttachment",
                    width: "100px",
                    hidden: true
                },
                {
                    field: "ItemIAM",
                    title: "Item Att/Mod",
                    width: "100px",
                    hidden: true
                },
                {
                    field: "Description",
                    width: "200px",
                    editable: false,
                    attributes: {
                        style: "background-color: lightgray; border-color:darkgrey"
                    }
                },
                {
                    field: "Width",
                    title: "Width / Length",
                    width: "60px",
                    headerAttributes: { "class": "wrap-header" },
                    attributes: {
                        class: "editable-cell"
                    }
                },
                {
                    field: "Height",
                    title: "Height / Thknss",
                    width: "60px",
                    headerAttributes: { "class": "wrap-header" },
                    attributes: {
                        class: "editable-cell"
                    }
                },
                {
                    field: "Depth",
                    width: "50px",
                    attributes: {
                        class: "editable-cell"
                    }
                },
                {
                    field: "Hinge",
                    width: "85px",
                    editor: hingeListDropdown,
                    attributes: {
                        class: "editable-cell"
                    }
                },
                {
                    field: "FinishSideLeft",
                    title: "Finish Side Left",
                    width: "100px",
                    editor: finishSideLeftDropDown,
                    headerAttributes: { "class": "wrap-header" },
                    attributes: {
                        class: "editable-cell"
                    }
                },
                {
                    field: "FinishSideRight",
                    title: "Finish Side Right",
                    width: "100px",
                    editor: finishSideRightDropDown,
                    headerAttributes: { "class": "wrap-header" },
                    attributes: {
                        class: "editable-cell"
                    }
                },
                {
                    field: "FromImplementorToFactory",
                    //field: "SpecialInstruction",
                    title: "Special Instruction",
                    width: "100px",
                    editor: editInpopup,
                    headerAttributes: { "class": "wrap-header" },
                    attributes: {
                        class: "editable-cell"
                    }
                },
                {
                    field: "ItemListPrice",
                    title: "Item List",
                    width: "75px",
                    editable: false,
                    format: "{0:n2}",
                    editor: nonEditor,
                    attributes: {
                        style: "background-color: lightgray; border-color:darkgrey"
                    }
                },
                {
                    field: "ItemGlobalListPrice",
                    title: "Global List",
                    width: "85px",
                    editable: false,
                    format: "{0:n2}",
                    editor: nonEditor,
                    attributes: {
                        style: "background-color: lightgray; border-color:darkgrey"
                    }
                },
                {
                    field: "Multiplier",
                    title: "Multiplier",
                    width: "75px",
                    editable: false,
                    format: "{0:n5}",
                    editor: nonEditor,
                    attributes: {
                        style: "background-color: lightgray; border-color:darkgrey"
                    }
                },
                {
                    field: "Markup",
                    title: "Markup",
                    width: "75px",
                    format: "{0:n5}",
                    editor: nonEditor,
                    attributes: {
                        style: "background-color: lightgray; border-color:darkgrey"
                    }
                },
                {
                    field: "ImplementorCostEach",
                    title: "Cost Each",
                    width: "100px",
                    //lockable: false,
                    editable: false,
                    format: "{0:n2}",
                    editor: nonEditor,
                    headerAttributes: { "class": "wrap-header" },
                    attributes: {
                        style: "background-color: lightgray; border-color:darkgrey"
                    }
                },
                {
                    field: "EachSell",
                    title: "Each Sell",
                    width: "75px",
                    editable: false,
                    format: "{0:n2}",
                    editor: nonEditor,
                    attributes: {
                        style: "background-color: lightgray; border-color:darkgrey"
                    }
                },
                {
                    field: "Total",
                    title: "Total",
                    width: "85px",
                    editable: false,
                    format: "{0:n2}",
                    editor: nonEditor,
                    attributes: {
                        style: "background-color: lightgray; border-color:darkgrey"
                    }
                }
            ],
            editable: {
               ...
            },
            change: function (e) {
               ...
            }

        });
}

function getItemPromptTemplate(pn) {
    if (pn != null)
        return "<strong style='color:rgb(129, 196, 104);cursor:pointer;'>" + pn + "</strong>";
    else
        return "";
}

function renderNumber(value) {
    if (value == undefined) {
        if (rowNumber == null || rowNumber == "0" || rowNumber === "")
            return "";
        else
            return rowNumber;
    } else {
        return value;
    }
}

var itemRowIndex = -1;
function IncrementItemRowIndex() {
    ++itemRowIndex;
    return itemRowIndex;
}
```

and here is what I am getting
[image: Out of alignment]

Answer (score 0):

There are many questions out there on misaligned headers in Kendo Grids.

One potential source of the problem is the scrollbar: when present, the header requires the following CSS rule:

```
.k-grid-header {
    padding-right: 17px !important;
}
```

Without a scrollbar, that padding must be 0.

If you want the scrollbar to appear and disappear dynamically depending on your data, check out this documentation: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/hide-scrollbar-when-not-needed